# z-index is working on mac PC only

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have popup on our website which works perfectly on website, but when I open same website on MAC, the menu specially come on top of the popup image.

I tried to add much z-index

Site

Dekastore.com
password - beta05

When website is opened, it show an video, and then it will move to website. where it shows two popup where i am having issue.

Comment: Hmm had a look but when filling in the password 'beta' I get a message that the password is incorrect.

Comment: Can't access the page using beta as password..

Comment: sorry password is updated its beta05

Answer (score 0):

In your html, your `#nav` class has a z-index of 9999, set it lower than your pop-up `z-index`.